# Add non homogeneous node to tree in a plugin view

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, treeview, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-emf

I'm working on a plugin and there's  a view which has a treeviewer.
I want to add nodes to that tree diagrammatically as these nodes are not children for input object (treeviewer.setInput(input object)

example:

I have x and y objects, and they are unrelated
x has child object x1 and child object x2

if I set the input for the tree viewer to x so i'll get x1 and x2 in my tree as they're its children

now, How can I add object y to this tree as a tree node while it has no relation with x

Thanks

Comment: I've known from eclipse forum also, that it can be done using 

        viewer.setinput(new ItemProvider(Collection))


and it worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have multiple root objects in a `TreeViewer`. You can get this by

- using the `ArrayContentProvider` as the content provider of the tree
- having the root objects of the tree as a array or `List`

Comment: Thanks Tonny, 
I have one more issue,

My program uses EMF AdapterFactoryContentProvider as the tree viewer content provider but I was using single root.

Now when I wanted to add multiple root I knew that I should use ArrayContentProvider

is there something like this in EMF or I should adapt all previous code to the jface ArrayContentProvider ?

Comment: Not sure. I have had a peek at the implementation, but it is not obvious whether it will work or not.